# Toutes ces émotions, ça creuse!

Tags: traduction

Dans une histoire que je lis, le personnage, Anne, est frustré d'essayer de nouvelles machines d'exercice. Il dit alors: "Toutes ces émotions, ça creuse!"

Est-ce à dire: "Toutes ses émotions en essayant les appareils d'exercice la rendent fatiguée et affamée"?

Merci!

Comment: Réponse courte : « Oui. »

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En général, l'expression "ça creuse" est en lien avec la faim.

C'est une expression.

Dans votre cas, je **dirais** que les émotions dues à son exercice sont éprouvantes et que celles-là lui donnent faim.

La piscine ça creuse! = L'effort de faire de la natation me donne faim

Comment: Je vous remercie! Cela a beaucoup aidé.